# How to interpolate into a Julia "for" expression?

Tags: metaprogramming, julia, expression-trees, abstract-syntax-tree

I was writing a macro [`@vcomp`](https://git.io/vwjO2) (*vector comprehension*) based on Python's list comprehensions with a conditional clause to filter elements in a succinct way.

```rb
macro vcomp(comprehension::Expr, when::Symbol, condition)
    comp_head, comp_args = comprehension.head, comprehension.args
    comp_head ∉ [:comprehension, :typed_comprehension] && error("@vcomp not a comprehension")
    when ≠ :when && error("@vcomp expected `when`, got: `$when`")
    T = comp_head == :typed_comprehension ? comp_args[1] : nothing
    if VERSION < v"0.5-"
        element  = comp_head == :comprehension ? comp_args[1] : comp_args[2]
        sequence = comp_head == :comprehension ? comp_args[2] : comp_args[3]
    else
        element  = comp_head == :comprehension ? comp_args[1].args[1] : comp_args[2].args[1]
        sequence = comp_head == :comprehension ? comp_args[1].args[2] : comp_args[2].args[2]
    end
    result = T ≠ nothing ? :($T[]) : :([])
    block = Expr(:let, Expr(:block,
                Expr(:(=), :res, result),
                Expr(:for, sequence,
                    Expr(:if, condition,
                        Expr(:call, :push!, :res, element))),
                :res))
    return esc(block)
end
```

Used like this:

```rb
julia> @vcomp Int[i^3 for i in 1:10] when i % 2 == 0
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
    8
   64
  216
  512
 1000
```

Which expand to this:

```rb
julia> macroexpand(:(@vcomp Int[i^3 for i in 1:15] when i % 2 == 0))
:(let
        res = Int[]
        for i = 1:15
            if i % 2 == 0
                push!(res,i ^ 3)
            end
        end
        res
    end)
```

I was expecting to be able to write `block` like this:

```rb
block = quote
    let
        res = $result
        for $sequence
            if $condition
                push!(res, $element)
            end
        end
        res
    end
end
```

Which gives the following error:

- `ERROR: syntax: invalid iteration specification`

Instead of the way I came up with:

```rb
block = Expr(:let, Expr(:block,
            Expr(:(=), :res, result),
            Expr(:for, sequence,
                Expr(:if, condition,
                    Expr(:call, :push!, :res, element))),
            :res))
```

However I was able to do it using `Expr(:for, ...)` directly as shown above and as far as I understand this is a parser error (is this a bug?). I have also been unable to find examples of this kind of interpolation, this is what I've tried:

```rb
julia> ex₁ = :(i in 1:10)
:($(Expr(:in, :i, :(1:10))))

julia> ex₂ = :(i = 1:10)
:(i = 1:10)

julia> quote
           for $ex₁
ERROR: syntax: invalid iteration specification

julia> quote
           for $ex₂
ERROR: syntax: invalid iteration specification
```

Construct whole expression and inspect it:

```rb
julia> ex₃ = quote
           for i in 1:10
               print(i)
           end
       end
quote  # none, line 2:
    for i = 1:10 # none, line 3:
        print(i)
    end
end

julia> ex₃.args
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 :( # none, line 2:)
 :(for i = 1:10 # none, line 3:
        print(i)
    end)

julia> ex₃.args[2].args
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 :(i = 1:10)
 quote  # none, line 3:
    print(i)
end

julia> ex₃.args[2].args[1]
:(i = 1:10)

julia> ex₃.args[2].args[1] == ex₂    # what's the difference then?
true
```

This works but is less readable:

```rb
julia> ex₄ = Expr(:for, ex₁, :(print(i)))
:(for $(Expr(:in, :i, :(1:10)))
        print(i)
    end)

julia> ex₅ = Expr(:for, ex₂, :(print(i)))
:(for i = 1:10
        print(i)
    end)

julia> eval(ex₃)
12345678910
julia> eval(ex₄)
12345678910    
julia> eval(ex₅)
12345678910
```

Is there a way I can use the more terse syntax instead? I find the current implementation difficult to read and reason about compared to what I was expecting to write.

Comment: this is all a bit unnecessary though, isn't it? there are many ways to emulate the conditional list comprehension that are still one-liners. e.g.
using logical indexing and a compound statement: `[i^3 for i = (A = 1:10; A[A % 2 .== 0])]`, using the conditional operator: `deleteat!((A = [i % 2 == 0 ? i^3 : nothing for i in 1:10]; A), find(A .== nothing))`, or using the filter function:  `[i^3 for i in filter((x) -> x%2 == 0, 1:10)]`. No need to go through all that trouble ...

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou *one liner* is not the same as **succinct**, even if I used one of your methods, it would be in combination with a macro (so I can write it the way I want), since I wouldn't want to write what you suggested (over and over again) and that is precisely the purpose of macros. This macro was an exercise for me to learn metaprogramming, so I think it was worth the trouble, from your suggestions I would only consider the last one, the one with `filter`, since it's performance is comparable to `[i^3 for i in 1:n if i % 2 == 0]` in Julia v0.5.0-rc0 and also to my `@vcomp` macro.

Comment: Well, fair enough. I agree that "oneliner != succinct", but I think all three versions above, if split over two lines, become very readable and reasonably succinct, whereas the use of an obscure macro would be less comprehensible to anyone other than the original author. But I agree, it's a very nice macro to play with for the purposes of experimenting with the language :)
It's good that an official version is coming soon though, I don't know why it wasn't considered as essential from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, I belive that comprehensions with guards are coming to Julia (in v0.5?).

To answer your question: The parser wants to be able to verify that its input is syntactically correct without looking into the actual value that is interpolated. Try eg

```
x, y = :i, :(1:10)
quote
    for $x = $y
    end
end
```

Now the parser can recognize the relevant parts of the syntax. (And you should get the same AST if you use `for $x in $y` instead.)

Comment: To be fair, I don't see a reason why this error can't be produced during lowering instead of parsing. `let x + y` is also wrong, but this error is a lowering error instead.

Comment: Comorehensions with guards are now available 0.5-pre.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I agree with @Fengyang Wang in that this should be a lowering error, I'll ask at julia-dev about that.